# Using google big query to count different number of rows which match on 3 specific columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let us say a table has 10 columns. I want to count number of rows for corresponding to each unique triplets of column 1, column 2, and, column 3. Each of the column 1,2, and 3 have random strings and I don't know what those entries are.

Example:
Let us say if the table looks like the following:

```
Col1     | Col2     | Col3    |.....Col10
-------------------------------
abc      | abcd     | efgh     |
-------------------------------
xyz      | abcd     | efgh     |
-------------------------------
abc      | abcd     | efgh     |
-------------------------------
abcfg      | abcd     | efg     |
-------------------------------
abcfg      | abcd     | efg     |
-------------------------------
```

Then I expect the the output to be as follows:

```
abc      | abcd     | efgh     | Count: 2
-------------------------------
xyz      | abcd     | efgh     | Count: 1
-------------------------------
abcfg      | abcd     | efg     | Count: 2
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want `group by`:

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(*)
from t
group by col1, col2, col3;
```